# code not generating proper output as I expected

Tags: angularjs

This is state code which I have written I just moving to state venueDetails with data which I have pushed in venueView.

```
$state.go("venueDetails", {
    venueView: JSON.stringify($scope.venue)
});
```

Now in next controller I receive data by using `$stateParams` in `venueinfo` variable.

```
var venueinfo = $stateParams.venueView;
```

Now I have to print data according to there respective id in html file.

```
for (var i = 0; i < venueinfo.length; i++) {
    if (venueinfo.[i].d == d) {
        $scope.vinfo.push(venueinfo[i]);
    }
}
```

Or in place of `var venueinfo = $stateParams.venueView;`

I should write this line: `$scope.venueinfo = response.data;` ?

Anyone suggest me which one is correct format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just parse it to json

```
var venueinfo = JSON.parse($stateParams.venueView);
```

or like this

```
var venueinfo = angular.fromJson($stateParams.venueView);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use JSON.parse

```
var venueinfo = JSON.parse($stateParams.venueView);
```